# Level loading works in Unity editor, but quits when deployed

Tags: unity, loading, levels, debugging

In my level selection screen, all but the first level start out locked.

When I click on a level, it loads perfectly in Unity editor. However, when I build the game on a real device, the game stops as though I had pressed the back button on my device instead of launching the level.

What happened? How can I debug this, given it works fine in the editor?

Comment: Are your levels different scenes?

Comment: Yes they are different scenes !

Comment: Make sure you don't have any exceptions being thrown in the editor.  Also check out this: http://www.klonk-games.de/2013/11/tips-android-development/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When building your game, Unity will not include all the scenes by default. Ensure that your scene is included and checked in the build window. The build settings window appears after selecting build and displays the currently selected scenes to be built. You can also find it by selecting File->Build Settings. You may need to add the scenes yourself and then ensure they're checked to be included in the build.

Comment: Every scene is included. I have double checked that. If that the case unity won't be able to run everything fine in the editor (From splash to end Scene). All 16 scenes are included. It's even running  fine in PC & Mac Build but for android it's just stops, Same as If I tapped the back key. :( :(

Comment: OK, then you need to provide more information about how you're switching scenes, what kind of debugging you've done and so on. You'd help yourself a lot if you caught exceptions and wrote them to a log file. Right now, it's likely just failing horribly and ending the app.

Comment: Just as I mentioned that I am selecting scenes from my menu scene. When I click or tap on screen. Through RaycastHit I got the collider and after checking it's name I load my level with Application.LoadLevel(<Level Name - Whatever it is>);
The main problem is that it works fine from editor, In PC & MAC Builds but for android it's getting touches but not loading

Comment: Like I mentioned: Add exception handling and write out the log. Then you'll have all the information you need.

Comment: can I know how to write log file?

Comment: That's not a question to be addressed in the comments. Ask a new question.

Comment: :/ can I have your contact details plssss? I need it badly :( can you refer me to some developer who can voluntarily help me??? :/

Comment: Developers ARE voluntarily helping you by answering your question on this site.